# Unknown Project Type GUID

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I recently took over maintaining a silverlight application from a shop in the Ukraine,
and ran into an problem opening the csproj files. I checked [mztools](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx) and [onlinecoder](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html), as well as googling each of them, but was unable to identify two of them:

> 88A30576-7583-4F75-8136-5EFD2C14ADFF
>   4C25E9B5-9FA6-436c-8E19-B395D2A65FAF

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010 Express, if that's relevant.
Any insight as to what they are or how to find out would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to find out what application those `GUID` Id belongs?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to find out either what application I need, or what toolkit/SDK I need to add to visual studio to be able to open and edit the files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

88A30576-7583-4F75-8136-5EFD2C14ADFF is a CRM package GUID for plug-in packages.

You need to download the CRM 2011 SDK and install it. Then, in the SDK folder, run the tools\developertoolkit\crmdevelopertools_installer.exe

The other GUID, 4C25E9B5-9FA6-436c-8E19-B395D2A65FAF, I could not find online, but I suspect that this is just the plug-in GUID, since I only see this one in my plug-in project.